# Como accedo a objeto guardado en una clase(Composiciòn)

Tags: c#

Tengo dos clases contacto y telefono, lo que deseo es acceder al objeto telefono para posteriormente mostrar el Nombre del contacto con el nombre de la operadora y telefono que almaceno en una lista(Operadora y numero) pretendo mostrar en un DataGridView de C#. Estoy trabajando con WindowsForm

```
// Clase contancto
public class Contacto()
{
   public string Nombre {set; get;}
   private List<Telefono> _telefonos = new List<Telefono>();
....
....
 public void AddTelefono(Telefono _telefono)
 {
    _telefonos.Add(_telefono);
 }
}
// Clase Telefono
public class Telefono()
{
   public string Operadora;
   public string Numero;
}

// Clase Main
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Contacto c = new Contacto();
   c.Nombre = "Andres"

   Telefono t = new Telefono("Tuenti", "094582113");
   c.AddTelefono(t);



}
```

Comment: Puedes acceder a los elementos de una lista con el operador `[ ]` indicando una posición o internarlos mediante un `Enumerator` con un `foreach`.

Comment: Agrega las operaciones o metodos que usaras asi se puede definir la estructura o diseño de las clases; asi como un Telefono de operadora es unico o un contacto tiene mas de un telefono?  como puedes ver parece que tendras dos estructuras y el manejo de telefonos y contactas puede ser por medio de otra clase o servicio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar **Linq**:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = (from c in contactos
                            from t in c.Telefonos
                            select new
                            {
                               c.Nombre,
                               t.Operadora,
                               t.Numero
                            }).ToList();
```

En este código recorres la lista de contactos, y para cada contacto recorres su lista de teléfonos, obteniendo una lista de objetos anónimos donde cada elemento de esa lista contiene un objeto de tres propiedades (Nombre, Operadora y Numero). Esta lista de **objetos anónimos** se enlaza al **dataGridView1** a través de la **propiedad DataSource**.

Si tu **clase Telefono** tuviera una propiedad de tipo **clase Contacto**, podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = (from t in Telefonos
                            select new
                            {
                               t.Contacto.Nombre,
                               t.Operadora,
                               t.Numero
                            }).ToList();
```

De esta forma solo tienes que recorrer la lista de teléfonos, y como un teléfono tendría asociado un **Contacto**, pues podrías acceder al **Contacto** de cada teléfono de forma mas sencilla haciendo al código más sencillo y fácil de mantener.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Gracias @Japv, por tu respuesta fue muy util

Comment: @Andres no hay de que, si la respuesta te fue útil te agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada, gracias